# Anaconda Installation error on MAc OS

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I am tyying to install anaconda on my mac but at the last step of installtion it gives me following error:

```
installing: conda-env-2.4.5-py27_0 ...
Python 2.7.11 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
creating default environment...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sdb99/anaconda2/pkgs/conda-4.0.5-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/install.py", line 37, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/Users/sdb99/anaconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.11-0/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 430, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "/Users/sdb99/anaconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.11-0/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1272, in <module>
    import binascii as _binascii
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/sdb99/anaconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.11-0/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../../libz.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/sdb99/anaconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.11-0/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Any idea how i can get ahead from here?

Thanks!

Comment: What Mac OSX are you using? This information would be helpful. If your situation has since been resolved can you post the solution. I suggest also use edit to fix some of the misspellings in your question and question heading.

Comment: I was having this issue as well. Running the installer using `sudo` seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just update python to the next version and try installing Anaconda again.
I had python 2.7 and then I updated it to python 3 and I was able to install Anaconda graphical installer successfully.

Comment: You have to be careful though, if the if you other code isn't compatible with Python 3. Python 2 to Python 3 introduces breaking changes. It may be th be perfect doll button for th is (and many) cases. But users need to be aware (don't blindly just update Python 2 ->  3 everywhere.)

Comment: Also, this reads more like a Comment, than an Answer, according to SO guidelines in the help section.